# Ubuntu 14.04 Cron outputs file names with ^M at the end

Tags: cron, ubuntu-14.04, carriage-return

When I pipe output to a file in a cron job using the > operator, it always appends a ^M to the end of the file name. This shows up as a ? when I run ls in the directory but reveals itself as ^M when I edit the file in nano and go to save.

For example this command:

```
locale > locale.txt
```

Outputs a file named "locale.txt?" (i.e. "locale.txt^M")

I don't know why it does this, but I'm guessing it has something to do with environment variables. When I use > from a terminal it behaves properly. I've searched Google for this problem but apparently it doesn't like all these special characters in the query so I haven't found anything.

I've tried using mv to change the file name back to normal but it doesn't recognize the ? or the ^M character when I type in the file name.

I've seen that perhaps this is the carriage return "\r" character but I don't know why cron would put a Windows newline on the end of my file name. All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the cron or script file itself: it has DOS line separators (CRLF) instead of Unix (LF only). You can fix it using `dos2unix`.

Comment: This fixed it! Cron still can't directly use file names that end in ^M so I just piped the result of my file output operation to dos2unix like so: `locale > locale.txt | dos2unix`